# Scheme function call error

Tags: list, scheme, racket, function-call

When trying to run my program I keep running into this error:

```
function call: expected a function after the open parenthesis, but nothing's there
```

I cant seem to figure out what part of my code is wrong to fix the error. Can anyone point me in the right direction to where it is?

Here is the code that is generating the error:

```
(define (list2tree ls)
   (list2tree-help ls ()))

(define (list2tree-help ls tree)
   (cond ((null? ls) tree)
         (else (list2tree-help (cdr ls)
                               (insert (car ls) tree)))))
```

Comment: any reason why you never mark as accepted the numerous answers you've received in this site?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that this is invalid syntax for an empty list:

```
(list2tree-help ls ())
```

It should be:

```
(list2tree-help ls '())
```

Comment: In Racket, you can also use `empty`. That might be easier to understand than trying to explain to people why empty lists aren't self-evaluating in Scheme (unlike CL and Clojure).